# Line Chart not accepting date as column 0?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a table on which when the user clicks it generates a line chart for the selected row. The column 0 of the line chart is a string date so I want to format it to Date() in order to apply the DateRange Filter. I do the following

```
data.yearChart.forEach(row => {
  let dato =  new Date(row[0]);
  if(dato != "Invalid Date" ){
      row[0] = dato;
  }
  console.log(row);
});
```

In console log I see that all the rows get to be correctly turned to Date object but the chart throws
`a.getTime() is not a function`. So actually if I add the filter now, it appears correctly but the chart is still not drawn. I also have a Date formatter for the chart but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
 var formatChart = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
 formatChart.format(dataYear, 0);
 dateSlider.draw();
 chart.draw(dataYear, options);
```

That's pretty weird since line chart accepts date objects. I would upload more code snippets but the project got pretty chonky at this point and will do it only if needed.

So my question is, how can I make the line chart load with the dates so the date range filter can be applied?

Edit: my json data get loaded on click from php file

Comment: If it is at fixed index you can skip this based on index value, or you may consider checking for value `Date` and skip your conversion

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on this? Not sure I understand. If you mean the field date as an index, yes I believe it's fixed.

Comment: forEach callback can have two argument, `(row, index)`. Now add some condition in your function to skip your fixed index by comparing its value against `index`.

Comment: if you build your json in the format used by the data table's constructor, [found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), you can use the [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes?hl=en#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation) to send real dates, rather than strings which need conversion...

Comment: I've solved my previous issue, now I have a new one but similar to the previous. I updated my post. :)